# How to add local image resource in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to display an image as background of app home screen but unable to refer the local image placed in app directory. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you put the image in the assets folder right? and then link it to background in css?

Comment: @JoeLloyd thanks done.

Comment: did it work correctly?
I'll type up an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assets Folder**

To get images such as background images, icons or banners in your app that need to be in every version of the app make use of the assets folder. In here you can place these images, they are then accessible where ever you need them (css, js or html).

**Adding a background**

You can specify a background image using css

```
body {
  background-image: url("path/to/your/assets/image.png");
}
```